# Variable scope issue in a switch statement

Tags: go

I have a program that parses a log file and returns a slice of structs with populated data from the file.

Also I have written a function to add a struct item to the aforemetioned list.

But there is an error that says "Cannot use 'sf' (type *SegmentationFault) as type SegmentationFault" which stems from this function. How am I to solve this problem?

```
func (sfList *SegmentationFaultList) AddItem(item SegmentationFault) []SegmentationFault {
    sfList.Items = append(sfList.Items, item)
    return sfList.Items
}

func parseLogFile(logPath string) (s *SegmentationFaultList){
    logFile, err := os.Open(logPath)
    checkError(err, "Could not open your log file")
    defer logFile.Close()

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(logFile)
    parsing := false
    sf := new(SegmentationFault)
    sfs := []SegmentationFault{}
    sfList := SegmentationFaultList{sfs}
    var beginRegexp = regexp.MustCompile(`(?i).+\[err\]:F-(\d+): Dump: Segmentation fault at ([\da-z]+)$`)
    var endRegexp = regexp.MustCompile(`(?i).+\[info\]:Engine child with pid \d+ terminated`)
    var sfTextRegexp = regexp.MustCompile(`(?i).+\[err\]:F-\d+: Dump:(.+)`)

    for scanner.Scan() {
        beginMatch := beginRegexp.FindStringSubmatch(scanner.Text())
        switch {
        case beginMatch != nil:
            sf.pid = beginMatch[1]
            sf.sfAt = beginMatch[2]
            parsing = true
        case endRegexp.FindStringSubmatch(scanner.Text()) != nil:
            parsing = false
            sfList.AddItem(sf)
        case parsing:
            sf.sfText = append(sf.sfText, strings.TrimSpace(sfTextRegexp.FindStringSubmatch(scanner.Text())[1]))
        }
    }
    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return sfList
}
```

Comment: You have a pointer value (`*SegmentationFault`) and you are trying to use it as a `SegmentationFault`.

Comment: Because `new(SegmentationFault)` returns a `*SegmentationFault`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are passing a pointer value (`*SegmentationFault`) where you just want a value `SegmentationFault`.

Instead of

```
sf := new(SegmentationFault)
```

You should do:

```
sf := SegmentationFault{}
```